# Can not send email with php mailer using gmail account

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here i cannot send the email with PHPMailer using my gmail account.
Sample Code:

```
<?php
require_once('phpmailerclass/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->Port = 568;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->Username = "myEmail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "myPassword";

$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails

$mail->From = "ramalingam.p@pickzy.com";
$mail->FromName = "Ramalingam";

$mail->addAddress("yoursramalingam@gmail.com","Luu Van Minh");

$mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
$mail->Body = "Hi,<br /><br />This system is working perfectly.";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
     echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}   
else
{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}      
?>
```

**Response Error:**

```
Message was not sent

PHPMailer Error: The following From address failed: myEmail@gmail.com
```

I am also enable 'less secure' in gmail settings.
But it will throw above the error. Specifying my VALID gmail From address.
Please correct where i am wrong.

Comment: I think GMail doesn’t allow you to send emails with a `From` address different from the actual account that you used to “login” to the SMTP server.

Comment: Shouldn't your port be 587?

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an obsolete example. I'd suggest you [update](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you use ssl then change port 587 to 465

```
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: Mail wasn't sent in localhost and it will throw the same error while i am running localhost. But the live server is working fine. Any idea?

Comment: Check open ssl is enable or not, if not enable then go in php.ini file enable openssl, find this code ;extension=php_openssl.dll and remove first semi colon.

Comment: It enables already. But the mail wasn't sent. From PHP info -> `OpenSSL support :  enabled `

Comment: Add one parameter $mail->SMTPDebug = true; in code and check what is exact error. post that error here.

Comment: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
The following From address failed: ramalingam.p@pickzy.com

Comment: Did you add parameter in your code?   $mail->SMTPDebug = true;

Comment: Yes. I was added in my code. After that Iam getting this error.

Comment: May be you using old lib of php mailer, please try with latest lib from here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer or may be there was some issue in your xampp or wamp.

Comment: Sorry, I am using the old version.It's working fine after update. Thanks!